# Rotate encryption key fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to rotate my SQL encryption key with the following script, but get an error while executing, although the compiler does not give an error. Anyone an idea on how to solve this?

```
ALTER COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY [myKeyName]  
ADD VALUE  
(  
    COLUMN_MASTER_KEY = [myNewKeyName]
);
```

FYI, I already created a new key 'COLUMN MASTER KEY' with name [myNewKeyName]

Error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'ADD'.
```

[Official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-column-encryption-key-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current)

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using and what compatibility level is your database?

Comment: SQL server/database on azure (version 12.0.2000.8 - compatibility 150)

Comment: Upon testing, the problem is your lack of parameters in your `VALUE` clause. As shown in the documentation, you should also be passing the `ALGORITHM` and `ENCRYPTED_VALUE`. When adding both of those, you don't get an error. The reason they are shown as optional in the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-column-encryption-key-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#syntax) section is because they are not valid for `DROP VALUE` statements (which the documentation states).

Comment: Thanks, any idea on how (and where) to get the ENCRYPTED_VALUE? (when new master key is generated by keyvault?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting Thom A's comment as answer here.

- When using the  `ADD VALUE`  clause in the  `ALTER COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY`  statement, `ALGORITHM`  and  `ENCRYPTED_VALUE`  parameters are required

Here is the corrected query with the required parameters:

```sql
ALTER COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY [myKeyName]  
ADD VALUE  
(  
    COLUMN_MASTER_KEY = [myNewKeyName],
    ALGORITHM = 'RSA_OAEP',
    ENCRYPTED_VALUE = 0x016E000001630075006D0062007200690061006E00630065006C006C006F0073006500720076006900630065002E0063006F006D002F00730071006C002F0072006F006F0740000001D7C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C7B9C
);
```

This query will add a new value to the encryption key with the specified column master key, algorithm, and encrypted value.

**Reference:** MS document on [Alter column encryption key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-column-encryption-key-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#a-adding-a-column-encryption-key-value).