# Get value for new SQL encryption key from azure keyvault

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-keyvault

Regarding my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77266418/rotate-encryption-key-fails), does anyone know how to retrieve the ENCRYPTED_VALUE for rotating the encryption key (see script below), when the new column_master_key_name is generated from the azure keyvault?

```
ALTER COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY key_name   
ADD VALUE   
(  
    COLUMN_MASTER_KEY = column_master_key_name,  
    ALGORITHM = 'algorithm_name',
    ENCRYPTED_VALUE =  <I NEED THIS VALUE>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Referred this MSDOC [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/key?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-key-show%28%29) to get  `ENCRYPTED_VALUE`

below this query i used

```
az keyvault key show --vault-name your-keyvault-name --name new-column-master-key-name --query 'key.n' 
--output tsv
```

- `az keyvault key show`: Displays the details of a key in a key vault.
- `--vault-name your-keyvault-name`: Specifies the name of the key vault.
- `--name new-column-master-key-name`: Specifies the name of the key.
- `--query 'key.n'`: Specifies the JMESPath query to filter the output. In this case, the query is filtering the output to only include the  `key.n`  property, which is the modulus of the key.
- `--output tsv`: Specifies the output format. In this case, the output format is tab-separated values (TSV).

**Result**
[image]

Comment: This is not possible only with SQL queries? (or in combination with c#)